# How to track issues sending mail to Yahoo with Qmail?

Tags: email

I've Qmail running under Plesk, here is the version:

psa-qmail-rblsmtpd-0.70-cos5.build92090714.19
psa-qmail-1.03-cos5.build92090714.19

The problem is that there are many emails(about 100) to Yahoo waiting in the queue, some of them are 2 or 3 days older.

Is there any way send a specific message from the queue and view the reason for Yahoo is 
blocking me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`/var/log/qmail/current` is a common location for the QMAIL logs.  You want to look at the logs for qmail-send, which will display the reason Yahoo is rejecting your e-Mail.

Answer (score 1):

For Plesk's qmail installations, the mail logfile can be found in `/usr/local/psa/var/log/maillog`. You can `grep` for e.g. the string `Remote_host_said` to get the exact answers of remote mailservers about deliveries.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo is known to operate strict anti spam measures. So the first step would be to check if your on any form of black list if you are deal with that and when its clear check to see if the trouble has resolved itsself.

http://www.mxtoolbox.com/